# Transferred files to new hosting, get SQL injection

Tags: php, security

I don't understand, I transferred my files to new hosting and now I can get SQL injection, even if I use mysql_escape_string or addslashes. Before that, I never could get an SQL injection. What's wrong? Please help, I am going crazy.

**edit:** There is no SQL injection if I use ", but it gives SQL injection, if I use '. My head will explode really soon...

Comment: Does the new host have the same version of PHP?

Comment: Uhm, could you provide the code you're using?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're going to need to be FAR more specific.

Comment: @davidjwest: The new hosting uses the newest version of PHP.

Comment: @hey I seriously doubt your host deploys **PHP5.4RC8** ;) You should use the [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension with its prepared statement functionality to avoid any possibility of SQL Injection. This is vastly preferable to a `mysql_real_escape_string` solution.

Comment: @hey: Which is the part of code that you can inject to? You have to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard to craft code that escapes/sanitizes inputs to a point where they would be safe to submit directly to a SQL database. What you really should do to make use of Parameterized Queries in your code for all interactions with your database. This allows your database to determine what should be considered "command" and what should be considered "data" so that injected SQL into the "data" will still be seen at data.

Read more at [OWASP's excellent discussion](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) about this topic.

Answer (score 2):

I thinks that `mysql_real_escape_string` is the function you want to use to protect your application from SQL injection....

Also make sure [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) are off...

Comment: Magic quotes is off (I checked) and I use mysql_real_escape_string, the same thing. :(

Comment: PDO prepared statements are even better.

Answer (score 0):

You may have had insecure code at the old host, and you just didn't know about it until you put the code at the new host, and people started attacking it there for whatever reason.